# Java duplicate methods combine

Tags: java, generics, methods

I have a method called `ReadTill` that has the same body of code but different parameter types. Could someone show me a strategy / code to combine them. I don't think that `InputStream` and `BufferedReader` share an interface, if they do, what is it and also if they didn't how would I do this?

I think the question should be, how can I do this with generics?

Thanks in advance.

```
public static void ReadTill(InputStream in, OutputStream out, String end) throws IOException {
    int c, pos = 0;
    StringBuffer temp = new StringBuffer();
    while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
        char cc = (char) c;
        if (end.charAt(pos++) == cc) {
            if (pos >= end.length()) {
                break;
            }
            temp.append(cc);
        } else {
            pos = 0;
            if (temp.length() > 0) {
                out.write(temp.toString().getBytes());
                temp.setLength(0);
            }
            out.write(cc);
        }
    }
}

public static void ReadTill(BufferedReader in, OutputStream out, String end) throws IOException {
    int c, pos = 0;
    StringBuffer temp = new StringBuffer();
    while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
        char cc = (char) c;
        if (end.charAt(pos++) == cc) {
            if (pos >= end.length()) {
                break;
            }
            temp.append(cc);
        } else {
            pos = 0;
            if (temp.length() > 0) {
                out.write(temp.toString().getBytes());
                temp.setLength(0);
            }
            out.write(cc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use generics here? Generics are to used in cases when a method argument or a variable takes in fact an Object but is accessed as if it were typed with specific class. There are no such variables in your case.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Reasons: 
A) wanted to clean up code, thought they would
B) see how they'd be used for educational purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those classes (`InputStream`, `BufferedReader`)does not implement the same interfaces nor extend the same class, but you can creat one from the other:

```
public static void readTill(InputStream in, OutputStream out, String end) throws IOException {
    readTill(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)), out, end);
}

public static void readTill(BufferedReader in, OutputStream out, String end) throws IOException {
    // as before
}
```

And usually, Java method names are camelCase, so I changed it in the example.

Comment: Do you know how I can do it with generics?

Comment: For the reasons I wrote at the top of my answer,  I'm not sure it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just off the top of my head, untested:

```
public static void ReadTill(InputStream in, OutputStream out, String end) throws IOException {
 ReadTill(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)), out, end);
}
```